# Assigning response data into an array (angularjs)

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular js, i wanted to assign the suncorp data which is equal to response into an array , what's wrong with the code? . is the result an array of data? . btw dont worry about the services its working the data is from an api (https://jobs.search.gov/jobs/search.json?query=nursing+jobs).

```
function TESTController($scope, testFac) {
    /* console.log("TESTControlleris now available.");*/
    $scope.data1= [];
    testFac.getData().then(function(response) {
    $scope.data1 = response.data;

          console.log("Data:",$scope.data1);
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `response.data` is not an `array`, and you want the data in an array then, you need to push data to array using array push method;

```
function TESTController($scope, testFac) {
    /* console.log("TESTControlleris now available.");*/
    $scope.data1= [];
    testFac.getData().then(function(response) {
    $scope.data1.push(response.data);

          console.log("Data:",$scope.data1);
    })
```

Comment: the data from the api is an array :)

Comment: if the response is an array, than you don't need to use  push method.

Comment: Thank you Sir. I do really Salute to programmers or people from India. (bow)

Comment: What is the problem you facing ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module("app",[]);
app.controller("postcontroller", function($scope, $http){
$scope.getAllProjects = function() {
        var url = 'https://reqres.in/api/products';
        $http.get(url).then(
            function(response) {
            $scope.projects = response.data.data;
            },
            function error(response) {
              $scope.postResultMessage = "Error with status: "
                  + response.statusText;
            });
      }
      $scope.getAllProjects(); 
 });
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="postcontroller">
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="project">Project:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <select id="projectSelector" class="form-control">
          <option id="id" ng-repeat="project in projects"
             value="{{project.id}}">{{project.name}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```